# Which package contains merge function in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to merge 2 channels in an iteration so that I can retrieve both channels values for each step.
I wrote the following lines

```
ch1, ch2 := make(chan int), make(chan int)
go Walk(t1, ch1)
go Walk(t2, ch2)

for ints := range merge(ch1, ch2) {
    fmt.Println(ints)
}
```

but when I run it, I get "prog.go:31: undefined: merge".
I would like to know where this merge function is located.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't such a function in the standard library, you'll have to define it yourself.

From your code, it seems that you've read [this post](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines) which already gives an example of `merge`, a user-defined function:

```
func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan int) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

*source: http://blog.golang.org/pipelines*

Comment: Oops, I just quickly jumped to the usage without paying attention to details above and thought it was part of standard library. I am still learning the basics and supposed that I could easily find a function merging 2 channels. Does it mean that I have to write it on my own or is there any alternative ?

Comment: As I've mentioned in my updated answer, you'll have to define it yourself.

Comment: Though it is simple enough to implement, I think the merge function from that blog post would be a nice addition to the standard library. I assume it is implemented the same often enough to warrant it. I can't figure out in which package it would belong though.